# Get Azure AppSettings in a Controller

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, application-settings, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 application hosted on Azure, and I added a new Application Settings `MyNewSetting` for my App in the Azure Portal.

How do I access that setting from a controller?

My code bellow:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();

    services.Configure<AppSecrets>(Configuration);
    services.AddSingleton<ITableRepositories, TableClientOperationsService>();
    //...
```

My Controller:

```
public class RecordController : Controller
{
    const int MyNewSetting = 7; // this one to replace with Azure Setting one
    private readonly ITableRepositories repository;

    public RecordController(ITableRepositories rep) {
        repository = rep;
    }
```

Here, I need probably to add `FromServices` injection, but I am not sure if it will work...

**EDIT:**

Folowing the @dee_zg answer, the following code could probably do the job:

```
public class RecordController : Controller
{
    int MyNewSetting = 7;
    private readonly ITableRepositories repository;

    public RecordController(ITableRepositories rep) {
        repository = rep;
        int myInt;
        if (int.TryParse(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_NEW_SETTING"), 
                         out myInt)) {
            MyNewSetting = myInt;
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose to either get them from `AppSettings["your-key"]` collection or as environment variables: `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("your-key")`.

From there you can map them to your custom IOptions and inject wherever you need them.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few things you can do.

1. Use [Options and configuration objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration#using-options-and-configuration-objects)

   > The options pattern uses custom options classes to represent a group of related settings. We recommended that you create decoupled classes for each feature within your app.
2. Use an [IOptionsSnapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration#ioptionssnapshot).

   > `IOptionsSnapshot` supports reloading configuration data when the configuration file has changed. It has minimal overhead. Using `IOptionsSnapshot` with `reloadOnChange: true`, the options are bound to `Configuration` and reloaded when changed.
3. ... (see documentation)

In short, have a look at [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration), determine the scenario that best fits your needs and have at it!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already saw that documentation before asking the question. Say, I know what to use, I don't know HOW to use, this is why I added some code.

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't ask if the code in example were useful for my case.